# How Do I Check To See If PEAR Is Installed On My Server or Not?

Tags: php, email, pear

I am getting error like:

> Warning: include_once(Net/SMTP.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/lib/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 348
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Net/SMTP.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /usr/local/lib/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 348
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Net_SMTP' not found in /usr/local/lib/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 349

My code:

```
require_once 'Mail.php';

$from = "me@example.com>";

$to = "you@gmail.com>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$host = "mail.example.com";

$username = "me";
$password = "test";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 }
```

Answer (score 26):

if you have ssh access, you can login and run

```
which pear
```

if it's installed it will print something like this

```
/usr/bin/pear
```

Comment: this is the answer, select it.

Answer (score 14):

Use this code

```
require_once 'System.php';
var_dump(class_exists('System'));
```

When this is true, pear is installed.
More info: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Comment: `require_once` exits the script with a fatal error, if the module was not installed. This is why you should check first if the module is installed (see this question above). Thus this is not an answer to the question above at all.

Answer (score 4):

The following code might help if the server is on ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear

sudo pear install mail

sudo pear install Net_SMTP

sudo pear install Auth_SASL

sudo pear install mail_mime
```

[More info here](http://www.markstechstuff.com/2009/04/installing-pear-mail-for-php-on-ubuntu.html).