# Can't confirm if Pear is installed or not through?

Tags: php, wamp, pear

I'm using Windows XP, Wamp... i have used this code to check if pear works according to [this thread's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326475/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-pear-is-installed-on-my-server-or-not) second answer:

```
require_once 'System.php';
var_dump(class_exists('System'));
```

It shows the following error:

> Warning: require_once(System.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\wamp\www\phptry\chkp.php on line 2

and this one too:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\wamp\www\phptry\chkp.php on line 2

This is my first time trying to use pear and so the possibilities of stupid mistakes is high! I feel I've not mentioned the path properly in the environment variables.. But not sure how to solve this!

I've tried following all the steps mentioned in the pear manual but might have made a mistake.. Please give your answer considering I'm a newbie!

Please help and don't close this question because there is nowhere else I could solve this... It has happened a number of times, people close the questions for "I don't understand type of reasons" and my problems remained unsolved.. Thank you!

Comment: have you checked if the files are there or not?

Comment: there? Where? in C: or E:? @NooBskie

Comment: System.php s in here>> E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\pear@NooBskie

Comment: No results in C:   @NooBskie

Comment: I can clearly read **C:\php\pear** in your include_path

Comment: Yeah! Stupid mistake :| @ÁlvaroG.Vicario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the pear running by changing the path of the include_path which was C:/WINDOWS to the place where my pear directory was! Then restarted the server and Voila! Got that thing running!